# Manga where the main character and his family are isekaied to a world where there is an apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This is a manga where the main character is very good at sexual technique and his family has been brought with him to a world where there is an apocalypse and he uses his technique on the people at that world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know whether this was in full colour or mostly black & white.

Comment: it was in mostly black and white

Comment: Do you recall which family members were isekaied with the MC? Mother? Father? Brother/s? Sister/s? Etc.

Comment: Were the isekaied family members blood related, or stepsiblings/stepmother by marriage? What kind of apocalyptic world was it, real-world future with destroyed skyscrapers etc, or more like a medieval kingdom overrun by fantasy monsters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably *[Game of Familia: Kazoku Senki](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/game-of-familia-kazoku-senki)*.

> The protagonist is **summoned to another world with his step-mother and two step-sisters**. Demi-humans are the rulers and saviors here, fighting undead monsters in groups of four called a "familia". Each person takes one of four roles: the swordmaster, the guardian, the healer, and the black mage. But to use magic power, one must offer part of their being as a sacrifice - the higher the sacrifice, the higher the power. Now the stranded family must decide who will take each role and accept the power - and consequences - that come with it.

I'm not certain I'd call this an apocalyptic world, but there are endless monsters described as "the enemy of all living things".

The manga is tagged with "nudity" and "sexual abuse"; a quick skim through it included a scene where a queen was convinced to join his side after a "massage", so presumably he has some technique.

Comment: thanks it was it